# Convert std::vector<uint8_t> to std::string_view

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++17, stdvector, string-view

I have some data of type `std::vector<uint8_t>`. I would like to interpret it as a string and do some sub-string check on it.

It can be done by converting it to `std::string` which will cause copying the data. Is it possible to somehow convert it to `std::string_view` and do search on it to avoid copying it.

Comment: Can we assume you can't use a `std::string` in the first place instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: I'm not writing a definitive answer, cause I've never used `string_view`, but since you can get the underlying pointer from the `vector` you could probs just have `string_view view((const char*)v.data());` but like... I dunno if that's _right_ or not. Some expert might be able to fault something with that

Comment: I can. I changed it already and it works. I can delete the question. Just interesting if it is possible int the case if we can't change original `std::vector<uint8_t>` to std::string

Comment: Do you want `uint8_t` view or actually `char` view?

Comment: Char view. Data actually is string

Comment: Are you sure that `uint8_t` is an alias for `char`? do you want exactly `std::string_view`, or would `std::basic_string_view<uint8_t>` suffice?

Answer (score 8):

Provided that `char` is 8 bits on your system (most systems are), you can simply `reinterpret_cast` the `vector`'s data to `char*` and make a view from that, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> data;
...
std::string_view sv(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data.data()), data.size());
```

Comment: `std::basic_string_view<uint8_t> sv(data.data(), data.size())` might work?

Comment: The proposed solution will print the memory representation of the string. It will behave differently depending on if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`.

Comment: @MooingDuck try CTAD and remove exlicit `<std::uint8_t>`.